# Crop intent not working for images taken from camera

Tags: android, image

The problem i am facing is i have 2 options take picture from camera or gallery.....if the user chooses the camera then the image is stored on the sdcard and then showed to user for cropping....but problem is when i try to crop that image it shows cannot load the image.....
P.S if the same image is selected from gallery option then there is no problem and im able to crop the image smoothly...any help would be appreciated

FYI.... i am getting the path of the image also

```
private void performCrop(Uri path) {
    // take care of exceptions
    try {
        Log.d(TAG,"path is in perform crop"+path);
        // call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not
        // support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(path,"image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
        // indicate output X and Y
        //cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        //cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(this, "This device doesn't support the crop action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Android does not have a `CROP` `Intent` action](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). There are many [image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one.

Comment: but how come when i add image from gallery i'm able to crop that image

Comment: You cannot do that either. A few gallery apps may elect to support some undocumented extras for cropping. However, there are thousands of Android device models, and these ship with hundreds of different gallery applications. There is no requirement that all gallery applications support undocumented extras for cropping.

Comment: ok so i have no choice but to use a library :(..thats a pain...but thank you so much for your comments